# Error in Firebase Functions after deploying Nuxt 3 app + VueFire

Tags: firebase, vuejs3, nuxt3, vuefire

I recently encountered this error after deploying my Nuxt app to Firebase.

```
Error: Failed to read credentials from file service-account.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'service-account.json'
  at .readCredentialFile ( /workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/credential-internal.js:507 )
  at .credentialFromFile ( /workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/credential-internal.js:480 )
  at .getApplicationDefault ( /workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/credential-internal.js:401 )
  at .AppStore.initializeApp ( /workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/lifecycle.js:34 )
  at .initializeApp ( /workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/lifecycle.js:102 )
  at undefined. ( file:///workspace/node_modules/firebase-frameworks/dist/firebase-aware.js:10 )
  at .ModuleJob.run ( node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:195 )
```

I'm using Nuxt 3 and Vuefire to do it. I already set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in my env and `service-account.json` exists in project root with correct values. What am I doing wrong?

### Some more context

I created my project using Nuxt's usual `npx nuxi@latest init <project-name>` command. And then I ran `firebase init` on that directory and point it to my project in Firebase.

After that I added VueFire and followed the config instructions provided at these pages:

- https://vuefire.vuejs.org/nuxt/getting-started.html
- https://vuefire.vuejs.org/nuxt/auth.html

Per the instructions for setting up Authentication, I downloaded my service account file and put it at the project directory as `service-account.json`. I reference it in my `.env` file, like so:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=service-account.json
```

Still, when built and deployed, I find the error I quoted above from Google Cloud Function in the logs. And the site throws `500` when one visits any page. It's like somewhere in the build or deployment process the environment variable gets dropped.

Comment: What specifically do we need to do to reproduce this error?  Please edit the question be specific and show code and directory structures as appropriate.  What you're describing now is difficult to imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution is to *not* provide `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable. Firebase Hosting/Functions automatically sets this variable to the proper credential so you don't have to.

The documentation does not say anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible solutions.

1. copy `.env` + `service-account.json` to `.output/server` folder after the build. You can use **post**build script in `package.json` to execute your copy command right after the build.
2. set the one-line-json content of `service-account.json` as value of GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in `.env`

see in https://vuefire.vuejs.org/nuxt/environment-variables.html#Admin-SDK